# Xtext - solving ambiguity without semantic predicates?

Tags: c, grammar, semantics, predicate, xtext

**Problem**

```
Entry
    : temp += (Expression | Declaration | UserType)*
;

Declaration
    : Type '*' name=ID ';'
;

Expression
    : temp1 = Primary ('*' temp2 += Primary)* ';'
;

Primary
    : temp1 = INT
    | temp2 = [Declaration]
;

Type
    : temp1 = SimpleType
    | temp2 = [UserType]
;

SimpleType
    : 'int' | 'long'
;

UserType
    : 'typedef' name=ID ';'
;
```

Rules `Declaration` and `Expression` are ambiguous due to the fact that both rules share the exact same syntax and problems occur because both cross references `[Declaration]` as well as `[UserType]` are based on the terminal rule `ID`.

Therefore generating code for the grammar above will throw the ANTLR warning:

```
Decision can match input such as "RULE_ID '*' RULE_ID ';'"
using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
```

**Goal**

I would like the rule to be chosen which was able to resolve the cross reference first.

Assume the following:

```
typedef x;

int* x;
int* b;
```

The AST for

```
x*b
```

should look something like:

```
x = Entry -> Expression -> Primary (temp1) -> [Declaration] -> Stop!
* = Entry -> Expression -> Primary '*' -> Stop!
b = Entry -> Expression -> Primary (temp2) -> [Declaration] -> Stop!
```

Therefore

```
Entry -> Declaration
```

should never be considered, since

```
Entry -> Expression -> [Declaration]
```

could already validate the cross reference `[Declaration]`.

**Question**

Because we do not have semantic predicates in Xtext (or am I wrong?), is there a way to validate a cross reference and explicitly choose that rule based on that validation?

*PS: As a few might already know, this problem stems from the C language which I am trying to implement with Xtext.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the current version of Xtext, **semantic predicates are not supported.**

Cross-references are resolved to their terminals (in my case `UserRole` and `Declaration` to terminal `ID`). And only during the linking process references are validated, which in my case is too late since the AST was already created.

**The only possible way** to use context sensitive rule decisions is to actually define an abstract rule within the grammar that states the syntax. In the example above, rules `Expression` and `Declaration` would be rewritten to one. Semantic validation then follows in the necessary areas such as content assist with the use of scoping.